# Is there a typescript type for HTML elements that doesn't accept React Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm making a React component that I want to only accept HTML elements as children, but not React components. For example:

```
// Good
<MyComponent>
  <div>hello</div>
</MyComponent>
```

```
// Bad
<MyComponent>
  <SomeOtherComponent />
</MyComponent>
```

Is there a type I can assign to the `children` prop of `MyComponent` in order for it to only accept standard HTML elements as children? I'd like to see a typescript error if the 'bad' example above is attempted, but no error if the 'good' example is attempted.

Comment: I don't think there's a type to do that, you cannot type it to Element or HTMLElement  but what you could do is to type your children to ReactNode or JSXElement and then check its type and render it conditionally.